# react native - undefined is not a function updateState()

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm passing a function from Parent to Children components using FlatList but for some reason, the error occurs that undefined is not a function referring to `updateState` function.

Here's the parent component:

```
class Home extends Component {

  /*
    data items here
  */

  updateState(data) {
    this.setState({ data: data });
  }

  renderItem() {
    return (
      <ItemView updateParentState={ (data) => this.updateState(data) } />
    )
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.fragmentContainer}
        data={this.state.items}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={this.renderItem} />
    )
  }
}
```

Here's the child view:

```
class ItemView extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      data: "some data" 
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => this.props.updateParentState(this.state.data) }>
        <Text>Item name here</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should fix your problem:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <FlatList
        style={styles.fragmentContainer}
        data={this.state.items}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem={this.renderItem.bind(this)} />
    )
  }
```

You should always use the `.bind(this)` function if you're going to pass a function as props so that `this` does not get lost. Or you could use the arrow function if you're not a fan of `.bind`.

Ex:

```
{() => this.renderItem()}
```